# PHP - stripout header

Tags: php, http-headers

I've made a proxy system with CURL.
I do need to access the header, but I also want to be able to separate the header from the content.

All was working fine until I ran into that response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2011 15:36:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<h1>Gestion des actualitées</h1>
```

I try to separate the header from the content using:

```
strpos($httpResponse, "\r\n\r\n");
```

But the problem is that this will cut the header right after the "100 Continue". Note that I don't create the header, it's a default behavior of Apache...

Do you have a good way to separate the header from the content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try altering the request to include `Content-Length`.

```
$content_length = //parse field  
$total_length = strlen($httpResponse);  
$body = substr($httpResponse, $total_length - $content_length);
```

Comment: id do `'HTTP/1'` so it matches 1.0 too

Comment: Well I can't access the content-length header, as my header is cut after the 100 CONTINUE.

Comment: Well it's because most of the time, we have 1 header. But in that case, the continue is the first header, and the "real" header follow. And the content may have the \r\n\r\n boundary in it. So I can't just "cut". The detection must be wize and aware of the context. CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE seem to understand that it must not cut at the first boundary, and know where the real content start. And if I cut the header after 100 CONTINUE, the content will contain the second header ( the one including the content-length )

Answer (score 2):

Based on the brian_d idea, I've come up with:

```
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ressource);
$headerLength = curl_getinfo($ressource,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = substr($httpResponse, 0, $headerLength);
$content = substr($httpResponse, $headerLength);
```

I think that's ok...